# Delete Yahoo mail top contact and suggested searches

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo, yahoo-account

I need to know how to delete Yahoo mail top contact and suggested searches in Yahoo search bar. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No way to delete a top contact.
But you can delete a contact, via Contacts icon (top right, with a number = current date day number): click on contact, click on three periods ... (more contact options); then Delete and OK confirmation. Need Sign out.

For Suggested Searches is more simple. Just click the X in the right of Suggested Searches list. That suggested search will be replaced with another.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with suggestions for contacts I had not even saved. It can be done. It's not straight forward, but it works perfectly (in the desktop-browser version):

1. Generate the "Top Contact" you wish to delete from the right-hand column (where Top Contacts are listed)
2. Click on the Contact (this will simply open the data fields)
3. Change the name (first/last), email address, and anything else...but the name/email for sure.
4. Save it (you will get an unable to save message)
5. Logout of Yahoo Mail
6. Log-in to Yahoo mail (same account you just logged out of)
7. Now open "Top Contacts" again and it will no longer display
8. The new email address you saved will now be located under "All"
9. Click on the newly saved contact and click on the 3-Dot-Ellipse
10. Select Delete

You Have successfully completed an otherwise impossible task

Answer (score 0):

If you have an email address with an apostrophe, like barry o'flanaghan, you can't delete it from suggested searches. They didn't think of it.

Also, while you can delete top contacts after a very big effort, it just replaces them with the next top contacts.